# Automatically get latest version when you open solution/project

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to force to Get Latest Version when you open a solution, project or website? Using VS.NET 2008 & 2010 on TFS 2008.

Comment: with visual source safe .. tools --- options --- source control in visual studio

Comment: You mean "Get Latest version of item on checkout"? It doesn't do what I want.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There's an option in VS 2010 (and 2013) that may be what you're looking for:

Tools > Options > Source Control > Environment

Select "Get everything when a solution or project is opened"

[image]

Comment: is there any way to avoid the "Get" dialogue box?

Comment: Is this possible in 2013?

Comment: Is this missing in VS 2015?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31862272/where-did-the-setting-get-everything-when-a-solution-or-project-is-opened-go-i