# Where did the setting "Get everything when a solution or project is opened" go in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In visual studio 2010\2013 there was an option to get latest on solution open, it seems to be missing for 2015.

Anyone know where it went?

[image]

Comment: These look like options from some source control add-in. Where was this UI in 2012/2013?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's been removed for now, see the explanation below:

> Late in the ship cycle, we found that the async project load improvements caused a fairly large issue with this feature.  Namely, if you had this feature enabled, you were very likely to see VS deadlock if it tried to get sources while also asynchronously loading projects.  Given that this feature is, in general, a bad practice, and fixing it would have been a fairly significant investment, we decided to remove it.

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1907270f-d513-4fb7-b3c5-1966743c30c1/get-everything-when-a-solution-or-project-is-opened-in-vs2015?forum=tfsversioncontrol)

There's a Microsoft feedback link with no substantial reply yet [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1599888).

Comment: And the feedback link now seems to be dead too?

Answer (score 1):

I know I am a little late with this, but you can use Source Control Explorer, right-click on your project and select Advanced. There you have the Get Specific Version. There you can select which version to get. Not as good as in VS 2013, but it will have to do for now. HTH