# Visual Studio 2012 - Automatically Get Latest Version

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, ide

I've been bumping into an issue lately where developers on our team (mostly me) have a tendency to open a project and forget to Get Latest Version before coding and we end up making new changes to old code.

It'd be nice if Visual Studio would know that I'm about to make new changes on old code and either warn me or automatically grab the latest version for me.

Is this possible?

EDIT: I forgot to mention I'm using TFS

Comment: You didn't mention what version control you are using. I don't think that there is anything Visual Studio can do to detect if your code is out of date. If you used something like Git, you could just make sure to initiate a Pull before writing any new code (in fact if you used Git, it requires you to Pull before being able to Push if your local repository is not current with the remote repository).

Comment: I'm using TFS. Sorry, I forgot to mention in the question.

Comment: If using Team Foundation Server see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722366/automatically-get-latest-version-when-you-open-solution-project).

Comment: Thanks. Looks like @JayMee has your answer.

Comment: It's mentioned that that particular solution is considered bad practice and was removed from the 2015 version of VS. Why is it considered bad practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question, and fortunately for you the answer is 'yes' (since you're using TFS as specified in your comment).

Go to Tools > Options > Source Control (on the left) > Environment and ensure 'Get everything when a solution or project is opened' is checked.

I must add, though, settings like this shouldn't really be used as a substitute for good habits and best practices. You and your team should be aware of the importance of 'get latest' to the point whereby you *want* to get latest and don't want to work without it (if you're at that stage in the project).

**Potential 'downsides' to this:**

On the odd occasion, you'll hear our team members say "don't get latest yet". Because of a bad check-in they've made. If they break the build - you'll get that broken build. Not an ideal scenario, it should never happen, but the reality is that it does. You lose an element of that control if it does it automatically.

Not to mention the fact that if your team are forgetting to get latest, there's an even bigger chance of them forgetting to check the changeset for potential issues. The 'resolve conflict' dialog doesn't always highlight *every* issue you need to be aware of.

I suppose a really minor downside could also be the start-up time of the project (one of the reasons Microsoft more recently got rid of this feature as you mentioned). You're not just opening a solution anymore, you're opening it and waiting for a get latest. Which could, then, require further attention (conflict resolution).

I'm possibly rambling now - but what about when you take on juniors that might not be familiar with source control concepts such as get latest? If it's always been taken care of, they might miss a trick. For example, hypothetically, VS opens but fails to connect to the TFS server as it's temporarily down. Could this cause an already forgetful team to explicitly get latest at a later date?

Comment: Well, I definitely WANT to Get Latest Version... I just forget every once in a blue moon. My fault, for sure. You mention best practices, is there a downside to using 'Get everything when a solution or project is opened'?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. To summarize then, best practice is to do it manually and force yourself to remember. The automatic option is convenient but can cause the user to be too reliant on it and cause problems if another dev checks in bad code or VS can't connect to the TFS server?

Comment: It's up to you to be honest mate. We're now venturing into the territory of opinion and whether it suits individual teams or not. Try both approaches, and choose what works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help!