# Team foundation server / Visual studio - notify if files/project has changed

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Hello fellow programmers.

This might seem like an odd question and I hope you could perhaps point me in the right direction.

I'm using team foundation server, to share my projects with fellow colleagues, and sometimes as you know, people have done some coding on your project either while you have been sick, away for vacation or something similar.

Lets pretend I have amnesia and I'm to forgetfull to click "Get Latest (Recursive)" on my project to get the latest changes.

Is there a way to automatically notify me if a project or it's files has changed when I open it in Visual studio?

Or could I perhaps code a tool/plugin which could notify me, and if so how would I get started?

Comment: Which version of TFS and visual studio you are using ?

Comment: I'm using VS 2010, so my guess is TFS 2010

Answer (score 3):

There's an option in VS 2010 (and 2013) that may be what you're looking for:

Tools > Options > Source Control > Environment

Select "Get everything when a solution or project is opened"

[image]

Referred [Here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722366/automatically-get-latest-version-when-you-open-solution-project)

Comment: Or if you want to do it programmatically:http://www.aymanzaza.com/2012/01/15/get-latest-changeset-history-from-version-control/

Comment: Thank you.. I'll look into it. Seems promissing